# xsd.exe output filename

Tags: .net, xsd, xsd.exe

Is there a way to control the output filename from xsd.exe?

My specific issue is that if an imported xsd is referenced this is added to the filename.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/8ab41df8-69d4-44e4-8795-436088f230e2) suggests another alternative ... using a path character in specifying the input schemas resets the generated file name. So if you use the following you will be able to control your output file name.

```
xsd.exe schema1.xsd schema2.xsd .\schema3.xsd
```

Will force `xsd.exe` to generate the `schema3.cs` file.

**Note:** It's a hack but up to now (VS 2010) it works.

Comment: +1, Exactly what I needed! (works even when schemas specified in the parameters file)

Comment: Keep in mind, that the ".\" must be used on the last file. If needed, reorder your input file names in the command.

Comment: Or, use xsd.exe /p:parameters.xml  .\schema3.xsd  for those joyful situations where you have a few hundred schema files to include

Answer (score 18):

To add to AxelEckenberger's answer there is a very slight improvement on the hack if you are doing this regularly (i.e in a batch script). Create an empty schema file with the output name that you want to use

**`Output.xsd`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

Then you don't need to rename the output

```
xsd.exe schema1.xsd schema2.xsd schema3.xsd .\Output.xsd
```

Now the output file will be named `Output.cs`.

Answer (score 11):

xsd.exe will automatically choose the output name of the file based on the input file name. You can only choose what directory to output it to with the /o switch.

That said, it's trivial to wrap this in a batch job, that would do what you want.

```
rename output.cs yourname.cs
```

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: Please see @Obalix's answer.

No. Only the output folder:

```
/o[ut]:directoryName
```

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx).